# How do you calculate the average?

Tags: derivatives, average, standard-deviation, delta-method

I've working on a project which involves datasets with points at, what should be, regular intervals.

However, due to things such as down times / reboots / outages, the data collected (from sensors) may have holes in it, be offset, etc.

A simple approach I was thinking of was iterate through the datapoints, calculating the delta between each point and the last before using the *modal* delta as the interval at which the sensor, in this case, should be outputting -- I don't have access to the actual interval.

Do you think this would suffice, or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what "average" means.

Comment: @J.G. Average delta

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the delta ? Or to estimate the size of the holes ? Or to recover missing data ? What is the dispersion of the unperturbed deltas ?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, but is it mean, mode, median, what?

Comment: @J.G. that's the whole point of the question.....

Comment: @Yves Daoust I'm trying to estimate the delta at which the data should be outputting. I.e. a sensor may be set up to output once an hour, but occasionally not do so. What's the best way to approximate the set up interval

Comment: What is the dispersion of the unperturbed deltas ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust layman's terms?

Comment: Say every hours plus or minus how much ?

Comment: ........ I don't think you have understood the question.